# Complexity of finding sequence of numbers in a matrix

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

The interview question was that there is a matrix with integer numbers. Find the length of the longest sequence of numbers increasing by one. Directions allowed are [left right up down].

```
4 2 2
5 6 3 
7 5 4
```

For example here `2 3 4 5 6` is the longest sequence.

I answered by saying we go over each number, recursively try to find the sequence for that number by visiting its 4 neighbors. Then I was asked what is the complexity of your algorithm. I said `k * (4 ^ k)` since I go over each number (hence the k) and then for each one I can see its 4 neighbors. k is n * n meaning number of elements in the matrix. But I am not sure if my answer for complexity is correct. Cause on the other hand I am thinking at most for each number we visit all the numbers in the matrix, which in that case complexity would be `k ^ 2.`

Comment: Can't you reduce the complexity by marking elements included in a sequence as visited? Once you've looked at the 2 and found the 3, 4, 5 and 6, there's no point in e.g. looking at the 3 again.

Comment: I think for this one, you need to do a Depth First search on each element looking for increasing sequence and update the longest for which the complexity would be O(k^2) where k = mn. because for one DFS it is O(V+E) = O(mn).

Comment: @m69 if you mark them visited, for example starting at 4 and marking 5, 6 as visited you get 3 as length, later when you start at second 2 in the first row, you won't reach 6 because it was marked as visited. Probably you mean for a given Depth First Search you mark them as visited, but later the visited matrix should be reset.

Comment: The complexity you're asking about seems infinite (unterminating) unless you provide more specific details about the recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method and example run-through**

We can do this more efficiently if we create a second grid in which we will store the number of steps that can be taken upwards from each cell. Let's use this example:

```
3 1 2 5               - - - -
4 2 5 6               - - - -
5 3 4 7               - - - -
6 7 5 4               - - - -
```

We start with the first cell (top left 3), check whether it has a neighbour with value 4, and if it does, we move to that cell and look for a 5, and so on; we get stuck at the cell with value 7. We mark this last position with a 1, and walk backwards, marking the cells 2, 3, 4 and 5:

```
3 1 2 5    x - - -    5 - - -
4 2 5 6    x - - -    4 - - -
5 3 4 7    x - - -    3 - - -
6 7 5 4    x x - -    2 1 - -
```

We now know that the top left cell is the start of a 5-step upward sequence. Then we switch to the next unmarked cell, the 1 to the right of the 3; it has two neighbouring cells that have value 2; we start by moving right and get stuck at the 2. We mark that cell as 1 and go back to the starting point and mark it provisionally as 2.

```
3 1 2 5    - x x -    5 2 1 -
4 2 5 6    - - - -    4 - - -
5 3 4 7    - - - -    3 - - -
6 7 5 4    - - - -    2 1 - -
```

Now we follow the second path from the starting point, down to a 2 and a 3, then right to a 4, and then there are two neighbouring 5's; we try the 5 going down first, and get stuck at that cell; we mark it as 1 and go back to the 4 and provisionally mark it 2:

```
3 1 2 5    - x - -    5 2 1 -
4 2 5 6    - x - -    4 - - -
5 3 4 7    - x x -    3 - 2 -
6 7 5 4    - - x -    2 1 1 -
```

Then we try the 5 above the 4, and go on until we get stuck at the 7; we mark this as 1 and go back until we reach the cell that we provisionally marked as 2; its mark in the current path would be 4, which is higher, so we replace the 2 by 4 and go back further until we reach the starting point of this path, which was provisionally marked 2. The new mark is 7, so we replace the 2 by 7 to get:

```
3 1 2 5    - x - -    5 7 1 -
4 2 5 6    - x x x    4 6 3 2
5 3 4 7    - x x x    3 5 4 1
6 7 5 4    - - - -    2 1 1 -
```

We move on to the next unmarked cell, which is the 5 in the top right corner. It has one neighbouring 6, which is already marked 2, which means we can mark this cell as a 3 (you will see that it is indeed the start of a 3-step path from 5 to 7):

```
3 1 2 5    - - - x    5 7 1 3
4 2 5 6    - - - x    4 6 3 2
5 3 4 7    - - - -    3 5 4 1
6 7 5 4    - - - -    2 1 1 -
```

We move on to the next unmarked cell, which is the 4 in the bottom right corner. It has a neighbouring 5 which is already marked 1, which means we can mark this cell as a 2.

```
3 1 2 5    - - - -    5 7 1 3
4 2 5 6    - - - -    4 6 3 2
5 3 4 7    - - - -    3 5 4 1
6 7 5 4    - - x x    2 1 1 2
```

The second grid is now complete, and the highest number we have added to it is a 7, which means the longest sequence in the grid has length 7.

**Complexity**

We have visited each cell as part of a path, and walked back down the path while entering the values in the second grid, so the complexity is linear to the number of cells, or O(N). Of course, this method requires a second grid, so the space complexity is also O(N).

**Code example**

Here's a quick code example in JavaScript that I wrote to test out the method and check my assumptions about the time complexity. Results can be found below the code snippet.

```js
function longestSequence(val) {
    var dx = [0, 1, 0, -1], dy = [-1, 0, 1, 0]; // up, right, down, left
    var height = val.length;
    var width = val[0].length;
    var max = 0;                                // max length found so far
    var stack = [];                             // cells in the current path
    var len = [];                               // length of upwards sequence from each cell
    for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        len[y] = [];
        for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            len[y][x] = 0;                      // initialize length grid
        }
    }
    for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {          // iterate over every cell
        for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            if (len[y][x] != 0) continue;       // skip cells already checked
            stack.push({x: x, y: y});           // start from this cell upwards ...
            while (stack.length) {              // and do a depth-first search
                var cur = stack.pop();          // take current cell from stack
                for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {   // check four neighbouring cells
                    var nbr = {x: cur.x + dx[i], y: cur.y + dy[i]};        // get neighbouring cell
                    if (nbr.x < 0 || nbr.x == width || nbr.y < 0 || nbr.y == height) {
                        continue;               // skip if off-grid
                    }
                    if (val[nbr.y][nbr.x] == val[cur.y][cur.x] + 1) {      // neighbour has next value
                        if (len[nbr.y][nbr.x] == 0) {                      // neighbour not yet checked
                            stack.push(cur);    // this cell is not last in path
                            stack.push(nbr);    // move to neighbouring cell
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (len[nbr.y][nbr.x] >= len[cur.y][cur.x]) { // neighbour has higher length
                            len[cur.y][cur.x] = len[nbr.y][nbr.x] + 1;     // take length from neighbour
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (len[cur.y][cur.x] == 0) {   // no suitable neighbours ...
                    len[cur.y][cur.x] = 1;      // cell is end-point of path
                }
            }
            if (len[cur.y][cur.x] > max) {      // new maximum length found
                max = len[cur.y][cur.x];
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
}

var grid = [[3, 1, 2, 5],
            [4, 2, 5, 6],
            [5, 3, 4, 7],
            [6, 7, 5, 4]];
document.write(longestSequence(grid));
```

**Checking linear complexity**

It's not that straightforward to judge the complexity of this algorithm by looking at the code, with its nested loops. To check my assumption of linearity, I ran the code with grids of random numbers from 1 to 9, and added a counter to see how many cells in total were pushed onto the stack:

```
  grid size        cells     push/pop

   8 x    8           64           75
  16 x   16          256          297
  32 x   32        1,024        1,235
  64 x   64        4,096        4,912
 128 x  128       16,384       19,557
 256 x  256       65,536       78,254
 512 x  512      262,144      313,371
1024 x 1024    1,048,576    1,253,540
```

The results confirm that the complexity is indeed linear to the number of cells. The fact that the number of cells pushed onto the stack is around 120% of the number of cells in the grid, and not precisely 100%, is because cells are visited once, twice or more, depending on their position in a path (end-point, mid-point, cross-roads).

To give an indication of the real-world speed: the JavaScript version above solves a 1024 × 1024 grid in less than a second.

Answer (score 0):

There's a fun little trick by the way: sort the cells by value and assign each element 1 + the length of the longest achievable sequence marked in a previous connectable cell. For example:

```
4 2 2
5 6 3
7 5 4

2 2 3 4 4 5 5 6 7

2 -> 1
2 -> 1
3 -> 1 + 1 = 2
4 -> 1 + 2 = 3
5 -> 1 + 3 = 4
6 -> 1 + 4 = 5
7 -> 1
```

With duplicates, we would need for each value to create a hash of locations, so we can quickly find the connectable cells for the next element we traverse. `O(n*m * log(n*m))`

Answer (score 0):

> I said k * (4 ^ k) since I go over each number (hence the k)

It does not multiply complexity by k. You can safely add O(k) to ensure complexity is at least O(k), but you don't need to multiply complexity by k unless you go through ~k values in each step (recursive call).

> and then for each one I can see its 4 neighbors.

You see 4 neighbours, but unless you fruitfully fork recursion in each of them, it doesn't count. You could simply multiply by 4 to to reflect 4 choices, but constant will be removed in O math anyway.

Actually, by problem definition you can't use all 4 ways each time, because previous item is next to current one. So, at most you can fork by 3, and for obivous planar composition reasons it can't work for long time - matrix density is not enough. Unfortunately, I don't know easy way

Effectively, you make no more than n*number of different ways to each valid point * 4 (for next step).

Even though I have example for bad case that reaches O(2^k) complexity. Make diagonal fulfillment: 1 in left-top cell, 2 in next diagonal line, 3 in next diagonal etc. Finish at longest diagonal of matrix, right-bottom part filled with zeroes.

0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0

2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0

3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0

4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0

5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

> Cause on the other hand I am thinking at most for each number we visit all the numbers 
>   in the matrix, which in that case complexity would be k ^ 2.

Wrong, if you do it in simple resursive way without "visited" flags, recursion will make more than 1 visit of each cell. For matrix above you can mimic way with array of 6 elements with RIGHT=0 or DOWN=1 elements, obviously there is a way for each combination and obviously they are different, thus you have 2^6 different valid ways for number 6 visits.

There is one more thing. It's not practical to calculate complexity by result length or value. You have input values like matrix dimensions and it's what we generally use in O math, because people can't predict what answer they will get...

Comment: recursion will make more than 1 visit of each cell -> but can't we say starting from each cell worst case we visit all the elements in the matrix? So for each element at most k visits. And we have k elements in the matrix hence k * k?

Comment: In my example you can see k^2 steps. No way with simple unrestricted recursion it will be k^2, you need something like visited booolean array to reduce complexity from exponential to quadriple...